# pickle.dump() fails saving a complex object, but no exceptions thrown

Tags: python, object, pickle

I am trying to save a very complex object using `pickle`. The object's structure is omitted as it is quite complicated, yet it doesn't require as much memory (~5MB).

```py
nX = 20 
nY = 50
model = ComplexGridModel(nX, nY) # nX, nY number or elements in X, Y directions

# I don't think it's important but "model" is being use like this:
analyzer = OtherComplexObject(*args, **kwargs)
analyzer.model = model

start = time()
[...] # loop operations on model and analyzer
end = time()

# now the critical part
print("Finished in {:.2f} min".format(end/60 - start/60) ) # print elapsed time

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) # here crushes or sth like that, don't know
```

The above code creates the file `filename.pickle`, but it's empty with size 0 KB. When I comment out the `pickle` part everything works flawlessly, but I still want to save `model`.
There are 3 mindblown facts that I can't explain:

1. Everything works as expected, until I change nX > 24. So, everything works fine if e.g. nX=20.
2. No `Errors` are thrown, neither in my own code, nor during `pickle.dump()`.
3. When the bug happens, even the line **previous** to `pickle.dump()` i.e. `print(...)` doesn't execute and so do the next ones. Seems variables are deleted, as well. My Spyder editor displays them in the variable explorer but when I try to access them from the console it throws `NameError: name 'variable_name' not defined`.

I know it's a drug and I would surely suspect my code being faulty; but with no `Errors` I can't help it. If my code was at fault wouldn't it at least throw an `Error` prior to `pickle.dump()`?.

Comment: What's different about the `ComplexObject` instance when `nX` > 24?

Comment: It just uses more memory, for example bigger lists etc. It's - to simplify - a two dimensional grid, so I am increasing one dimension. I thought there might be a memory limit for pickle, but reading docs it's way greater than the required for e.g. nx=20.

Comment: Could just be a bug in `pickle`. You might be able to avoid it by using a different protocol. Try values in range 0..3. Protocol 4 was added in Py 3.4 to support very large objects (and might be the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`).

Comment: I tried and worked for 0, but only once. when I tried again it was the same. No sense.

Comment: That certainly is odd. Another workaround (assuming it's a bug) might be to add `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` methods to the class to get control over its pickling.